# Google map api - V3 Distance between two polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On one project , I recovered all the coordinates of the polygons of different postal code.
When I search a zip code, I draw the polygon using the google api.
Now I would like to know whether a given polygon is so much distance from another .
Is that possible ?

By parsing all my geojson , I need to know if a random polygon is 5km from the polygon drawn .

There is computeDistanceBetween method from the geometry library...but its for two points. Is there the same for the distance between two polygons ?

Thx u for your help

Comment: related question: [What is the fastest algorithm to calculate the minimum distance between two sets of points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700983/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-calculate-the-minimum-distance-between-two-sets)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would solve your problem but you can somehow use this library to compute distances within your polygon.

[BDCCgeo.js](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGeo.js)

There is a function called **bdccGeoDistanceToPolyMtrs()**, you can measure the distance between a point and a polygon edge or polyline. Perhaps you can get a certain point on your first polygon and compare with with the second using this function.

Reference:

[Distance from point within a polygon to polygon edge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895923/1109352)